# Gibt es eine Bezeichnung für einen Asylbewerber dessen Antrag positiv ist?

Tags: word-choice

Ein Asylbewerber ist im Prinzip kein Asylbewerber mehr, wenn seinem Antrag stattgegeben wurde. 
Aber wie nennt man ihn stattdessen am besten? Gibt es ein Wort dafür?

Comment: _Schützling_ und _Flüchtling_ könnte man verwenden, aber das eine ist ungewöhnlich, das andere wird auch schon vorher gesagt.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Formal wäre das ein Asylant. Allerdings wird der Begriff mittlerweile als abwertend wahrgenommen und zumindest von offizieller Seite nicht benutzt.

Solange das Antragsverfahren läuft, handelt es sich um einen Asylbewerber oder eine Asylbewerberin, nach positiver Entscheidung um **Asylberechtigte**.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asylbewerber):

> Während Asylbewerber Menschen mit einem laufenden Asylanerkennungsverfahren sind, werden anerkannte Asylbewerber als Asylberechtigte oder anerkannte Flüchtlinge bezeichnet.

(Die Bezeichnung "Flüchtling" weist auf eine etwas andere juristische Grundlage als bei "Asylberechtigter" hin. Details siehe Link oben.)

Comment: Ich habe mich für diese Antwort entschieden, da sie eine Quellenangabe binhaltet (auch wenn es Wikipedia ist, die das nicht weiter belegen) und somit m.E. die umfassendste Antwort ist.

Answer (score 12):

Wenn es ganz förmlich sein soll, kommt es auf den Grund für die Anerkennung an. Man unterscheidet dann zwischen Asylrecht, internationalem Schutz und subsidiärem Schutz. Je nachdem, welcher Schutzgrund vorliegt, gibt es dementsprechend drei Varianten des „Asylrechts“ im weiteren Sinne, in denen das Asylverfahrensgesetz die folgenden Begriffe verwendet:

- **Asylberechtigter** (im Falle des [Asylrechts gemäß Art. 16a GG](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asylrecht_%28Deutschland%29) - [§ 2 AsylG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/asylvfg_1992/__2.html));
- **Flüchtling** (im Falle des [Schutzes gemäß der Genfer Flüchtlingskonvention („internationaler Schutz“)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkommen_%C3%BCber_die_Rechtsstellung_der_Fl%C3%BCchtlinge) - [§ 3 AsylG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/asylvfg_1992/__3.html));
- **subsidiär Schutzberechtigter** (im Falle der [Schutzberechtigung gemäß der Qualifikationsrichtlinie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsidi%C3%A4r_Schutzberechtigter) - [§ 4 AsylG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/asylvfg_1992/__4.html)).

Answer (score 2):

*Ein* Wort? Nein. Soweit ich weiß, nicht.

Wird sein Antrag abgelehnt, wird er zu einem *abgelehnten Asylbewerber*.
Wird sein Antrag anerkannt, wird er zu einem *anerkannten Asylbewerber*.